# How to create an object type with a custom key in a function?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function that accepts a key and a value, and return a new object with that data. For example:

```
createObject('name', 'Foo'); // { name: "Foo" }
```

And I also want to make that function type-safe, which means that it should return a type with the key and its value type. For example:

```
type ReturnedType = { name: string };
```

I tried to do that, but I am getting an error:

```
type Obj<K extends string, V> = {
  [key in K]: V
};

function createObject<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): Obj<K, V> {
  // Type '{ [x: string]: V; }' is not assignable to type 'Obj<K, V>'.
  return {
    [key]: value
  }
}

const person = createObject('data', {
  name: 'Foo',
  age: 10
});

console.log(person.data.name);
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=31#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwDwGkoQB7AgOwCYDOUBwATgJY4DmANFAGoB8UAvFAN4CwAUFFANoBrCCCiUoKALoAuBjwC+Abh48AZgFccAY2DkA9jihbSEAIbZ4CCDtTosuQsTKVaDRgAphIWSjoA3UwAbdQhZegBKWUtUOiYOHj4AekSoABVwaABydgEMWRIKahkGRSh5TLEiHD1gKFMCAnIqHFM4QOhgPShQSChM6N83TIA6BKgTYHVSQy5ePgEvYoDgiDH5BRVuLQMSKEhSAgNWIxNzCEtrYHdMvHNTTLpZvhaAW1C+gDE9PQex0yp3gBGAAMCnCym4PG2OEO7WGgT0VHc+0OOGGt2ApmGrwg4KAA)

Comment: It's a design limitation in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#21030](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21030).  You'll likely need a type assertion somewhere.

Comment: Do you only want string key types?

Comment: Seems like a limitation of computed properties syntax type inference... not sure how to work around that though other than appending `as Obj<K, V>` to the object literal.